# Using an NO switch to close to ground as an interrupt

Tags: power-supply, low-power

I'm designing a circuit that supplies power via USB to an Arudino.  The USB power runs through a 3v3/5v dual regulator.  I'd like to use a small tactile switch in front of the IN lead on the regulator as an interrupt/reset apparatus, but I'm finding it difficult to obtain a suitable NC switch, though I have a variety of suitable NO switches on hand.

How reasonable is it to close the switch to ground as a means of interrupting power to the rest of the circuit?  As an example:

[image]

My assumption is that the resistance of the regulator and everything past it will make the closed-to-ground path better and should interrupt the power.  But I've never used an NO switch in this fashion and wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: What regulator are you using?

Comment: MIC5211 - http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic5211.pdf

Comment: Eh, specifically the MIC5211-LXYM6-TR

Comment: Why don't you use the enable pins of that device for turning power off with the push button?

Comment: I could, but I'm not sure it's effectively different since I just have IN hardwired to ENA and ENB.  It would still just have to interrupt to ground, even if I placed it between IN and ENA/ENB.

Comment: Put a 10 kohm resistor between EN and Vin.